# When creating an order via api, the salable quantity does not decrease

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, salable, reservations

I am using the API `/rest/V1/orders/create`, but when creating an order, the saleable quantity does not decrease. (Magento ver. 2.4.6-p3 community edition)
I am using this payload:

```
    {
    "entity": {
        "customer_group_id": 1,
        "applied_rule_ids": "2",
        "base_currency_code": "EUR",
        "base_discount_amount": 0,
        "base_grand_total": 96,
        "base_shipping_amount": 5.575,
        "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5.575,
        "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0,
        "base_subtotal": 86,
        "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 86,
        "base_total_due": 0,
        "base_total_paid": 91.15,
        "base_to_global_rate": 1,
        "base_to_order_rate": 1,
        "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
        "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
        "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
        "customer_is_guest": 0,
        "customer_email": "44611946045@amaro.com",
        "customer_firstname": "Danilo",
        "customer_lastname": "Duarte",
        "customer_note_notify": 1,
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "email_sent": 1,
        "global_currency_code": "EUR",
        "grand_total": 96,
        "order_currency_code": "EUR",
        "shipping_amount": 5.575,
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "shipping_description": "checkmo",
        "shipping_discount_amount": 0,
        "shipping_incl_tax": 5.575,
        "state": "new",
        "status": "pending",
        "store_currency_code": "EUR",
        "store_to_base_rate": 0,
        "store_to_order_rate": 0,
        "store_id": 1,
        "subtotal": 86,
        "subtotal_incl_tax": 86,
        "total_due": 0,
        "total_paid": 91.15,
        "total_item_count": 2,
        "total_qty_ordered": 2,
        "tax_amount": 0,
        "weight": 0,
        "items": [
            {
                "base_original_price": 43,
                "base_price": 43,
                "base_price_incl_tax": 43,
                "base_row_total": 86,
                "base_row_total_incl_tax": 86,
                "name": "Luma Analog Watch",
                "original_price": 43,
                "price": 43,
                "price_incl_tax": 43,
                "product_id": 41,
                "product_type": "simple",
                "qty_ordered": 2,
                "row_total": 86,
                "row_total_incl_tax": 86,
                "sku": "24-WG09",
                "store_id": 1,
                "weight": 0
            }
        ],
        "billing_address": {
            "address_type": "billing",
            "city": "Barueri",
            "company": "",
            "country_id": "BR",
            "customer_address_id": 4,
            "email": "44611946045@amaro.com",
            "firstname": "Danilo",
            "lastname": "Duarte",
            "postcode": "06414070",
            "region": "SP",
            "street": [
                "Rua Sol"
            ],
            "telephone": "11950807198"
        },
        "payment": {
            "additional_information": [
                "Check / Money order"
            ],
            "amount_ordered": 96,
            "amount_paid": 91.15,
            "base_amount_ordered": 96,
            "base_amount_paid": 91.15,
            "base_shipping_amount": 5.575,
            "method": "checkmo",
            "cc_exp_year": "0",
            "cc_ss_start_month": "0",
            "cc_ss_start_year": "0",
            "shipping_amount": 5.575
        },
        "status_histories": [
            {
                "comment": "Order Placed by Admin Username using Admin Panel",
                "created_at": "2024-03-15 16:54:05",
                "entity_id": 11,
                "entity_name": "order",
                "is_customer_notified": 0,
                "is_visible_on_front": 0,
                "parent_id": 75,
                "status": "pending"
            },
            {
                "comment": "Order Placed by Store Administrator",
                "created_at": "2024-03-15 16:54:05",
                "entity_id": 10,
                "entity_name": "order",
                "is_customer_notified": 0,
                "is_visible_on_front": 1,
                "parent_id": 75,
                "status": "pending"
            }
        ],
        "extension_attributes": {
            "payment_additional_info": [
                {
                    "key": "method_title",
                    "value": "Check / Money order"
                }
            ],
            "shipping_assignments": [
                {
                    "shipping": {
                        "address": {
                            "address_type": "shipping",
                            "city": "Barueri",
                            "company": "",
                            "country_id": "BR",
                            "customer_address_id": 4,
                            "email": "44611946045@amaro.com",
                            "firstname": "Danilo",
                            "lastname": "Duarte",
                            "postcode": "06414070",
                            "region": "SP",
                            "street": [
                                "Rua Sol"
                            ],
                            "telephone": "11950807198"
                        },
                        "method": "flatrate_flatrate",
                        "total": {
                            "base_shipping_amount": 5.575,
                            "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5.575,
                            "shipping_amount": 5.575,
                            "shipping_incl_tax": 5.575
                        }
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "base_original_price": 43,
                            "base_price": 43,
                            "base_price_incl_tax": 43,
                            "base_row_total": 86,
                            "name": "Luma Analog Watch",
                            "original_price": 43,
                            "price": 43,
                            "price_incl_tax": 43,
                            "product_id": 41,
                            "product_type": "simple",
                            "qty_ordered": 2,
                            "row_total": 86,
                            "row_total_incl_tax": 86,
                            "sku": "24-WG09",
                            "store_id": 1,
                            "weight": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "extension_attributes": [],
                    "stock_id": 1
                }
            ],
            "applied_taxes": [],
            "item_applied_taxes": [],
            "converting_from_quote": false
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what's missing here.

Answer (score 0):

After creating an order, a reservation of this product is made. This is MSI functionality. Read more at https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/inventory/. Only when the order is (paid and) shipped, the salable quantity will be lowered.

Comment: Exactly this reservation isn't happening when calling the API, this is in a testing environment, is there any configuration I need to make for the reservation to occur via API? When I create the order through the interface, reservation happens without any issues.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? There should be no difference between a regular order and an order through the API. I would suggest to disable all extensions and then try again.